# how to discard a branch and bring the changes from master

Tags: git, gitlab, branch

Our current workflow is such that every Monday morning, we want to discard all the commits merged to `temp` branch and mirror it with the latest version of `master` branch.

However, over the entire week, there would be commits made by different developers to the temp branch which would be pushed to Gitlab. We would like to reset the `temp` branch completely and bring it back to way `master` branch.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this. Here are two fairly straight forward methods: (note these assume your remote name is "origin"):

```
git fetch                           # make sure your remote copy of master is updated
git checkout temp                   # checkout the temp branch if not already
git reset --hard origin/master      # reset temp to remote master
git push --force                    # push out the new temp branch to origin/temp
```

You can collapse the middle two commands into one if you prefer:

```
git fetch                           # make sure your remote copy of master is updated
git checkout -B temp origin/master  # checkout/create temp and reset to origin/master
git push --force                    # push out the new temp branch to origin/temp
```

**Side note:** When force pushing, I almost always recommend using `git push --force-with-lease` so you don't accidentally blow away commits on the remote that you don't know about. However, I think this is one of the rare cases where you actually do want to use `git push --force` since it sounds like you want to reset the `temp` branch no matter what; even if someone pushed a new commit to that branch a few minutes ago.

**Another Side Note:** The Git repo itself uses a branching strategy called [Gitworkflows](https://hackernoon.com/how-the-creators-of-git-do-branches-e6fcc57270fb), which, like your strategy, has a throw-away branch that is used for integration testing, and is periodically reset. The Git maintainers call that branch `next`, which represents candidate features for the "next" release. (There's even a second level throw-away branch called `pu` for "proposed updates".) Just thought you'd be interested in knowing that you are using a(n arguably) tried and true strategy, at least regarding your `temp` branch.